# Get all users from JSON and put it into TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to parse this `JSON` on my APP and trying to put the result on a `TextView` from now I have the `JSON` in a `String`, this is my `JSON`

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
        "street": "Kulas Light",
        "suite": "Apt. 556",
        "city": "Gwenborough",
        "zipcode": "92998-3874",
        "geo": {
            "lat": "-37.3159",
            "lng": "81.1496"
        }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
        "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
        "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
        "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
},
```

.....

I tried this:

```
JSONArray users = new JSONArray(result);
tvNames.setText(users.get("name"));
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to get the name from a `JSONArray` and you need to iterate through it and find the `JSONObject` with the key "name", as follow :

```
private String getAllNames(String result){
        StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            JSONArray users = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0; i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
                names.append(user.getString("name")).append("\n");
          }
        }catch(JSONException ex){
            Log.d("Debug","Error parsing json " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return names.toString();
    }
```

Then you can do now with the result of that method

```
tvNames.setText()
```